# Django DB Models F Combined Expression

Tags: python, django, database, model

```
In [1]: from django.db.models import F

In [2]: from forum.models import Post

In [3]: post = Post.objects.get(id=1)

In [4]: post.view_count = F('view_count') + 1

In [5]: post.save()

In [6]: post.view_count

Out[6]: <CombinedExpression: F(view_count) + Value(1)>

In [7]: post = Post.objects.get(id=1)

In [8]: post.view_count

Out[8]: 3
```

After saved the post, it returned the combined expression.

I want the exact result (3).

is it possible to do without calling get method again / refresh_from_db ?

Answer (score 16):

In Django 1.8+, you can use the [`refresh_from_db`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.refresh_from_db) method. It won't save any SQL queries, but you might think the code is nicer.

```
>>> post = Post.objects.get(id=1)
>>> post.view_count
2
>>> post.view_count = F('view_count') + 1
>>> post.save()
>>> post.refresh_from_db()
>>> post.view_count
3
```

Since the update happens in the database, it's not possible to get the new value in Django without doing a `get()` or a `refresh_from_db` (which both cause a similar SQL query). However, it is possible to avoid the initial `get()` by using `update()` instead.

```
>>> Post.objects.filter(id=1).update(view_count=F('view_count') + 1)
>>> post = Post.objects.get(id=1)
>>> post.view_count
3
```

Comment: Thanks, 

It'll take time to refresh or reload DB model ? 

I used like below, 
post.refresh_from_db(fields=['view_count',])

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Do you want to know whether it will take longer to do `refresh_from_db()` or `get()`?

Comment: No, i am not comparing  get() & refresh_from_db(). Normally 10k users update the values at a time, the response of view count is slow or normal ?

Comment: You'll need to do some performance testing, I don't know how it will perform with 10k users.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#f-expressions,

Python never gets to know about encapsulated SQL expression `post.view_count = F('view_count') + 1  # F('view_count') Django sql expression`.

it is dealt with entirely by the database.

So changes done on Database while Python all knows about the expression you applied rather then result.

You can do it by this way directly:-

```
post = Post.objects.filter(id=1)
post.update(view_count = F('view_count') + 1)
```

Comment: It'll raise the attribute error:
AttributeError: 'Post' object has no attribute 'update'.
update will work list of query set objects.

In [14]: post = Post.objects.filter(id=1)

In [15]: post.update(view_count = F('view_count') + 1)
Out[15]: 1

In [16]: post[0].view_count
Out[16]: 5

Comment: @Muthuvel thanks, i went wrong with update `queryset`.

Answer (score -4):

Why don't you just write `post.view_count += 1`?

Comment: If we will use the F(),

getting the database, rather than Python, to do work and 

reducing the number of queries some operations require

Ref:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#f-expressions

Comment: But since you want to actually get the value there's no point in using `F`

Comment: if we will use F(), we can able to reduce the query time. is it correct ?

Comment: If you intend to pull one item there's no difference, the only difference is memory, so it's useful for a whole query of objects, not just one

Comment: The advantage of `post.view_count = F('view_count') + 1` is that it will *always* increase the value by one. If two users do `post.view_count += 1` at the same time, then the value might be updated by 1, not 2.